# implementing toolbar fo my UITextField in UITableViewCell using protocols in swift

Tags: swift, objective-c, delegates, uitextfield, swift-protocols

How to implement this code inside a Protocol in order to achieve Protocol Oriented Programing? One big problem is settling the @objc method, which are not allowed in protocols. Second one is this code is now used for UITextField inside many cells, that's why I extend UIView and why I corrected `endediting`

original code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61332009/how-can-i-show-done-button-on-the-decimal-pad-keyboard)

```
 //used inside a cell with a UITextField
    extension UIView {
    
    func toolBar() -> UIToolbar{
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = .default
        toolBar.isTranslucent = true
        toolBar.barTintColor = UIColor.init(red: 0/255, green: 25/255, blue: 61/255, alpha: 1)
        let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let buttonTitle = "Done"
        let cancelButtonTitle = "Cancel"
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: buttonTitle, style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(onClickDoneButton))
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: cancelButtonTitle, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(onClickCancelButton))
        doneButton.tintColor = .white
        cancelButton.tintColor = .white
        toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, space, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        toolBar.sizeToFit()
        return toolBar
    }

    @objc func onClickDoneButton(){
//        view.endEditing(true)
        self.endEditing(true)
    }

    @objc func onClickCancelButton(){
//        view.endEditing(true)
        self.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

EDIT on Sandeep Bhandari's answer this is the working implementation

first I added a file with

```
extension UIView: ToolBarProtocol {}
```

then inside my cell now I have:

```
 let selDone = #selector(onClickDoneButton)
    let selCancel = #selector(onClickCancelButton)
    self.cellTextfield.inputAccessoryView = toolBar(with: selDone, cancelSeclector: selCancel)

@objc func onClickDoneButton() {
        self.endEditing(true)
    }
    
    @objc func onClickCancelButton() {
        self.endEditing(true)
    }
```

Comment: Please paste the original code here. The idea is not being forced to jump to a different place to help you. Also why is there commented out code?

Comment: code is the same, the link is just for reference about its original context. The commented out code, is the only change I made, since the uitextfield is not inside a controller, but inside a TableViewCell (many cells on same controller)

Comment: @biggreentree: Please check the updated answer, thats why I wrote last comment as you cant provide default extension to `@objc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best you can do I guess is

```
protocol ToolBarProtocol where Self: UIView {
    func toolBar(with doneSelector: Selector?, cancelSeclector: Selector?) -> UIToolbar
}

extension ToolBarProtocol {
    func toolBar(with doneSelector: Selector?, cancelSeclector: Selector?) -> UIToolbar{
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = .default
        toolBar.isTranslucent = true
        toolBar.barTintColor = UIColor.init(red: 0/255, green: 25/255, blue: 61/255, alpha: 1)
        let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let buttonTitle = "Done"
        let cancelButtonTitle = "Cancel"
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: buttonTitle, style: .done, target: self, action: doneSelector)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: cancelButtonTitle, style: .plain, target: self, action: cancelSeclector)
        doneButton.tintColor = .white
        cancelButton.tintColor = .white
        toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, space, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        toolBar.sizeToFit()
        return toolBar
    }
}
```

**In nutshell** You can't provide a default extension to `@objc` protocol.

**What does it have to do with this problem?**

You cant provide a default extension to your done and cancel button selectors, because they will need to be annotated with `@objc` (Typical selector signature is **selector(@objc method)**) and as soon as you add `@objc` to them then compiler will give you a compilation error

> @objc can only be used with members of classes, @objc protocols, and
> concrete extension of classes

so to make your protocol compatible with `@objc` function you will endup making it @objc protocol, and if you make a protocol @objc you cant provide a default extension to that

For more details refer: [Swift protocol extension in Objective-C class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61656564/swift-protocol-extension-in-objective-c-class)

Comment: testing your answer, I get the problem I described inside the edited version of my question, it requires @objc in a loop

Comment: @biggreentree: Can you check the updated answer, I edited answer 2 mins ago

Comment: thanks for your solution, please, can you check If I implemented correctly? It is working, but I'd like your idea on it! I knew the origin of the problem, but could not apply your very simple and clear solution

Comment: @biggreentree: TBH this is what I have in my mind as well, hence I have upvoted the question, but if you get better answer than this please feel free to accept that :)